# SSRS ReportServer output is clipped in ie9 and ie10 iframe

Tags: html, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I have an iframe embedded deep within a webpage, this iframe is intended for displaying various SSRS reports. It used to work in ie9 and ie10 (still seem to work in ie8 and ie11), however some "upgrade" between version 9.0.5 and 9.0.43 broke displaying SSRS in iframes. What happens is that the report gets a very narrow width rather than using the entire area, so all reports gets clipped. Reports work fine in a tab by itself, it is just iframes that seem to be broken. If "Page Width" zoom is selected it does show everything, but it tries to cram it into the same very narrow space, making the text too small and unreadable. How can I get the same behavior as before (as ie8 and ie11) where it utilizes the entire width for the report instead of clipping the report? 100% width is specified on the iframe, however it does not seem to be pushed down. The top parameter seem okey, it is the report section. The zoom select button is not shown on ie11, not sure if that is related or not. Seems like regardless of what parameters I enter, they are all ignored. Tried this

```
rs:Format=HTML4.0&rv:ToolBarItemsDisplayMode=143&rv:DocMapAreaWidth=1500&rs:Command=Render
```

and it does not have any effect on output nor toolbar.

I have read about this issue elsewhere, however all "solutions" seem to be to revert the entire webpage back ie8 compatibility mode, that is just not an option  that is feasible for me due to the complexity of the web application.

The iframe I use looks like this

```
<iframe src='http://Host/ReportServer_SQLSERVER2008R2/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fBase%2fPeakRate&rs:Command=Render' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and errors and scouring through obscure websites describing internet explorer quirkiness etc. I found that using an

```
<object data="xx"/>
```

tag instead of

```
<iframe src="xx"/>
```

seemed to solve the problem. Also Compatibility View had to be turned on. Apparently ie9 does not handle iframes the way that other browsers does.